# Does bias in statistics and machine learning mean the same thing?

Tags: machine-learning, bias, bias-variance-tradeoff

In statistics, people often talk about unbiased estimators. In machine learning, *bias variance trade-off* is mentioned all the time.

Does bias in both contexts mean the same thing?

Does an unbiased estimator have a bias for the data it tries to model?

Comment: yes both biases are the same, they mean $\mathbb{E}_\theta[\hat{\theta}]\ne\theta$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they mean the same thing.

This free chapter covers bias and variance of estimators: http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/ml.html

Please see section 5.4, which has a good explanation of what they are.

Answer (score -2):

No, they don't. But they're similar.

In ML the **learning bias** is the set of wrong assumptions that a model makes to fit a dataset. That can be thought of as a measure of how well the model fits the training dataset.

On the other hand, the regular **statistic bias** is mathematically defined as the average of the absolute error of an estimator. If this number is zero the estimator (or model) is unbidden, if it is positive then the estimator is positive biased, which means the on average the estimation (or predictions) will be always higher than the true value.

They're different because **a model can have learning bias (it doesn't fit perfectly the data set) but it is unbiased (the average absolute error is equal to zero, or very close to zero)**.

For a more detailed explanation read this paper: http://www.cems.uwe.ac.uk/~irjohnso/coursenotes/uqc832/tr-bias.pdf

Comment: Bias has a strict mathematical definition in the context of the bias-variance trade-off. Your definition and the paper you provided, give a broader definition of bias introduced by Tom Mitchell. I don't think this applies to the original question.

Comment: I don't know why this was down voted multiple times. The linked paper directly address the original question.